# I don't have "Application" field in Logcat

Tags: android

I use Eclipse with ADT and according to [release notes](http://tools.android.com/recent/updatedlogcatviewer) for R14 preview now we can create filters using `Application` field. But it is always empty for me, for different applications, different log levels. Why? How can I use this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set debuggable to true

Comment: Having the same problem, this did not help

Comment: not precise, not really true, not usefull.. Because:

since SDK Tools, Rev8(Dec2010)
"Developers no longer need to add the android:debuggable attribute to the <application> tag in the manifest — the build tools add the attribute automatically. In Eclipse/ADT, all incremental builds are assumed to be debug builds, so the tools insert android:debuggable="true". When exporting a signed release build, the tools do not add the attribute. .."

sorry

Answer (score 0):

Clearing CatLog and restarting Eclipse helped me..

Comment: Didn't help me... Rebooted phone, restarted adb, restarted eclipse, cleared the log..... nothing